# Could I use directory junctions (symbolic link) to share music between 2 users in Windows 7

Tags: itunes, symbolic-link

I want to have 2 users be able to use the same itunes library and be able to sync an ipod which ever user is logged in.  I tried making both the My Music folders point to the same folder, but that didn't work.  One itunes would not store its library info in that folder.  I was wondering if I could create a junction directory so that I can have both My Music folders  redirect to a common library folder.  I've only read about directory junctions , I havn't tried them.

Comment: Directory Junctions are like drugs - you'll link your ituneses, and then you're hooked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, just make sure both users have adequate permissions to access the folder. You can use the command line tool `mklink` to create a directory junction:

```
mklink /j "C:\Documents and Settings\Someuser\My Documents\My Music\" C:\Music
```

replace their `My Music` folder location accordingly.

Comment: This is a great way to put your data on a separate hard drive, while still being able to use links to the normal "My Music/Documents/Pictures" folders.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, have iTunes use the "Public Music" folders instead, since all users already have access to these folders.

In Windows 7, this is C:\Users\Public\Public Music

I forget what it is in Vista, but it's probably similar. And in XP it's probably under C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Shared Documents or something similar.